# Running python project with import __main__ even with import error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a homework assignment in which i have to edit a very large project (add code in certain places). The thing is that the project has an `import __main__` statement which PyCharm underlines with a red curly line and says: "no mudule named `__main__`".

[image: This is what it looks like]

I don't quite understand how the project runs without crashing- when i debug that import line it is carried out and the debugger continues to the next line without crashing, probably recognizing the module and therefore is able to access its dictionary.

I've seen some posts stating it has to do with bug track in PyCharm. I tried resetting cache and it didn't help.

The project is in Python 2.7 and so is the configured interpreter.

The project works just fine from command line also.

Any ideas ?

Edit: I tried isolating the issue by opening an empty module, importing `__main__` in it, declaring a global variable and then accessing that variable - it worked even though PyCharm reported it as error with red curly line under the import statement. I really can't understand how it works (?)

Comment: Why do you want to import `__main__`?

Comment: `__main__` is the (synthetic) name of the module that was selected on the command line. So PyCharm is flagging this incorrectly. It may not be a *good idea* to import `__main__` from another module, but it can be done.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I don't want to import it, it's a project written not by me. I have to add code in certain places as an assignment.

Comment: Well, it's simple, that code has errors, remove it

Comment: @DanielPryden, So ignoring it is fine as long as the code is not mine and i only need to be able to run it ? I just have to add code in other places and to rely on the fact that the project works perfectly without my edits (the `__main__` was there before i touched the project). So i guess i can ignore it ?

Comment: It's a really hacky way of assigning global variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's PyCharm not quite understanding the import system. `__main__` is the name of the module Python creates for a program's top-level script, regardless of the name of the script's file.

PyCharm appears to be expecting a `__main__.py` file, but no such file is necessary. The code is fine.

Comment: I also have a `raise exception -some string-` in the code (instead of raise Exception(some string)), which also seems to bypass error check even though PyCharm sees it as an error. Does it fall in the same category ?

Comment: @chepner: No, it's incorrectly complaining. No `__main__.py` is necessary for `__main__` to be importable. Ever thought about those `if __name__ == '__main__'` blocks? Those run when you run a file as a script, because when you run a file as a script, it runs as the `__main__` module.

Comment: @caffein: That's a different, mostly unrelated question. You should post it as its own question, with a [mcve]. `raise exception -some string-` is too mangled for us to tell what's going on.

Comment: I know what the `__main__` module is, but it's a nonstandard enough use of an `import` statement that I don't really blame PyCharm for failing to special case it. (I've deleted my comment and retracted my downvote in light of the fact that the preexisting nature of the `__main__` module prevents the error when the script is actually run.)